# Deeplink into Spotify Search on iOS from Native App

Tags: ios, spotify

I have an application in the Apple app store that streams a live radio station and provides a list of tracks that have been played. The user can navigate to specific track in that list, tap a `Spotify` button and the user is directed into Spotify via `Deeplinking`, using the `Spotify` search route (example below):

**spotify://search/*artistName***

This feature was working great (about 85% accuracy search on artist name) until recently.  `Spotify` opens, but I receive a native alert:

**Couldn't Open Link** 
Spotify can't open this type of link on this device.

Did the search route change?
Did Spotify disable this feature?

[image: Spotify Alert]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the `//` from the URL works for me: `spotify:search:artistName`. Example in Swift:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "spotify:search:pink+floyd")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```